# Pandas - 'Series' object has no attribute 'Columns'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregation-framework, ffill

Tried to aggregate the values from the column C if the column A & B are null. I have tried the code, it was working fine for few tables and got a error for one of the table. Any Suggestions?

Code :

```
from tabula import read_pdf 
from tabulate import tabulate
from tabula import read_pdf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# guess=False, pages=page,stream=True

Page_No = 45
tables = read_pdf('/content/210812154731_DECK CRANE - MACGREGOR HAGGLUND - TG 5795-36.5 130-2 - N00024-93-C-2220 - PARTS MANUAL.pdf',  pages=Page_No)
data_df = pd.DataFrame(tables[0])
# data_df['Dump'] = data_df.iloc[:,0:1]

out= data_df.ffill().groupby(['Item', 'SMR','CAGE','Part Number','Qty'], as_index=False)['Description'].agg(' '.join)
```

[image]

DATA:

```
   A        B       C
12525    1FWE23   1H654D
                  14654        
24798    14654    S56E82
65116    63546    38945        
46456    46485    R68R45
                  AD545    
A5D66    45346    QA6683
```

EXPECTED:

```
   A        B       C
12525    1FWE23   1H654D 14654       
                   
24798    14654    S56E82
65116    63546    38945
46456    46485    R68R45 AD545    
                  
A5D66    45346    QA6683
```

Comment: @jezrael, I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: Can you explain more what not working?

Comment: What is `print (data_df.info())` ?

Comment: I see, need `out= data_df.ffill().groupby(['Item', 'SMR','CAGE','Part Number','Qty'])['Description'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()`

Comment: Also remove `, as_index=False` and added `.reset_index()`

Comment: @jezrael, Tried out the above code. But it was not working. I'm getting the result as empty dataframe

Comment: So if use `out= data_df.ffill().groupby(['Item', 'SMR','CAGE','Part Number','Qty'], as_index=False)['Description'].agg(' '.join)` it return ouput (wrong format), but if use  `out= data_df.ffill().groupby(['Item', 'SMR','CAGE','Part Number','Qty'])['Description'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()` it return empty DataFrame? Are you sure?

Comment: @jezrael, Yes when I use the first code, if any of the one column is entirely null, then it throws error. whereas if I use the second code, it throws empty dataframe